# How to fold comments in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I have written a lot of `javadoc` comments in my class and each function has a large description. When I open the class it is inconvenient to scroll down with all those comments in place.

Is there any shortcut for folding all the comments? I tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> it didn't work :(.

**Edit:** Most of the keyboard shortcuts don't work if there is any error in the workspace. I have no errors.

Comment: If you want to close all comments automaticly, you can set folding for comments. Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Folding -> Comment

Answer (score 11):

To fold comments go on 'Window' >> 'Preferences' and then in the tree, locate 'Java' >> 'Editor' >> 'Folding'. Select 'Enable Folding' and check 'Comments and Header Comments'.

Answer (score 5):

There is such function in Eclipse, but you need to assign a shortcut for it first.

[image]

Open *Window* (on Windows) or Eclipse (on Mac) - *Preferences* - *General* - *Keys* - *Collapse Comments*. Put focus to *Binding* field and press a key combination you want this command to be associated with. Make sure there is no conflicts mentioned in *Conflicts* list on the right hand side. If there is a conflict, choose another shortcut. Press *OK*. Now you should be able to collapse all comments in an editor.

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) who came here looking for comment folding in C++ CDT, there is another option:

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Folding
I checked "Comments" under "Initially fold these region types"

This will collapse all comments by default when you open a file in CDT.